# Установка GD для PHP на ОП MAC OS X

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу установить GD для PHP на ОП MAC OS X. 
После команды `sudo install php5-gd`
мне выдает:

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте установить с помощью [brew](https://brew.sh/)

```
sudo brew install gd
```